# jQuery Validate plugin - Disable error message on certain fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to disable the error message just for specific input fields on a form.

In this example i'm trying to disable the messege just for the radio input field.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $("form").validate();

  $('input[type="radio"]').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  
  $(document.body).on('click', '.submiter', function () {
  $("input").valid();
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <label for="title-Mr">Mr</label>
      <input id="title-Mr" type="radio" name="title" value="MR" class="required">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="bading">Bading</label>
      <input id="bading" type="text" name="bading" class="required">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
    <a class="submiter" href="#submit">submit</a>
  </p>


</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out by adding if statement to the errorPlacement function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $("form").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.is(":radio")) {
        return false;
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }

  });


  $(document.body).on('click', '.submiter', function() {
    $("input").valid();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <label for="title-Mr">Mr</label>
      <input id="title-Mr" type="radio" name="title" value="MR" class="required">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="bading">Bading</label>
      <input id="bading" type="text" name="bading" class="required">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
    <a class="submiter" href="#submit">submit</a>
  </p>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation at https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate. Just have a class that identifies fields you don't want to validate and use the 'ignore' option in the form.validate call:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $("form").validate({ignore: ".ignore"});

 
  $(document.body).on('click', '.submiter', function () {
  $("input").valid();
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <label for="title-Mr">Mr</label>
      <input id="title-Mr" type="radio" name="title" value="MR" class="required ignore">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="bading">Bading</label>
      <input id="bading" type="text" name="bading" class="required">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
    <a class="submiter" href="#submit">submit</a>
  </p>


</form>
```

Comment: That ignores the full validation that's not what I'm after. It still needs to validate. I answered it myself anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $('form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if(element.attr('id') == 'title-Mr'){
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  $(document.body).on('click', '.submiter', function () {
        $("input").valid();
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best options in this scenario are either:

1. If the radio button is not required, remove the `class="required"` attribute from the radio input.
2. Ignore validation of that element altogether by specifying `ignore: <selector>` inside of the `$().validate()` function.

   ```
   $('input[type="radio"]').validate({
       ignore: "title-Mr"
   });
   ```
3. If you want the radio button to still be required, but not display a message, specify a null message for that specific identifier.

   ```
   $('input[type="radio"]').validate({
       messages: {
           "title-Mr": null
       }
   });
   ```

According to https://jqueryvalidation.org/, the video on the front page explains a few different scenarios, each one becoming more and more complex.  The scenario that demonstrates how to specify basic customization explains that there are two main parts to be passed to the `$().validate()` function: "rules" and "messages".  Inside of "messages", the sub-keys are the ids for the form field message you are customizing.  There are other options available, such as "ignore".

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is required. This is just to hide the error message.

Comment: Then I would recommend going with #3.  That just specifies a custom message for that form element as being blank.